General solution of partial difference equation that generates Eulerian numbers
I have a question on the partial difference equation
$$f(n+1, k) = (k+1) f(n,k) + (n+1-k)f(n,k-1)$$
where $(k, n) \in \mathbb{Z}^2$.
It is well known, that under some boundary conditions this equation generates Eulerian numbers.
I did not find any information about the general solution of this PDE. Is it known?

This question is similar to: Difference equation $A(n,x)=p(x)A(n-1,x-1)+q(x)A(n-1,x)$. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This equation is different to one you have given a link to, because the coefficients in the equation I wrote do not solely depend on one variable.

Apologies, I see. But I'll still leave the link to that other question since it seems possibly relevant.

Thank you for the link!

It's an instance of the Knuth-Graham-Patashnik recurrence. Check out this paper.

Dear Max Alekseyev, thank you for the great reference!
